# how to pass codeigniter DB array to javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, codeigniter

i have this database array in codeigniter that i want to pass it to the javascript function. is it possible?

MODEL:

```
public function show_employment_skills($P1)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('employee_skills');
    $this->db->where('emp_id', $P1);
    $this->db->order_by('ID', 'desc');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                    'id' => $row->ID,
                    'emp_id' => $row->emp_id,
                    'skills' => $row->skills


                );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data = "";
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and after getting the $data (that is a DB array, right?)

here's my controller

```
 public function swoosh_employment_skills()
{
    $P1 = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $set['record_skills'] = $this->emp->show_employment_skills($P1);
    $this->load->view('swoosh_template/employee/employmentskills',$set);

}
```

the $set['record_skills'] is the array came from the database..

now here's my view:

```
<?php if ($record_skills != "") } ?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>Skills</th>
<th style='width:50px;'>Alert it!</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($record_skills as $row): ?>
<tr>   
    <td class="skills"><?php echo $row['skills'];?></td>
    <td><img src=alert_it.png onclick="show(db array that i should put. but how?);"</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

here is the javascript

```
function show(array){
 //in here i should alert all the values of arrays. ..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for that, like:

```
<img src=alert_it.png onclick="show(<?php echo json_encode($your_array); ?>);" />
```

and in js

```
function show(arr){
 console.log(arr); //check the array format and loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<img src=alert_it.png onclick="show('<?php echo json_encode($your_array); ?>');" />
```

Then you pass the string to the function in JS, and then in the JS you can decode that string as JSON:

```
function show(arr){
    var _json = $.parseJSON( arr );
    console.log( _json ); //check the array format and loop
}
```