# Passing Query Result to Javascript in HTML View Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

i've trouble when trying to pass my Query result to JS in my view. Is There any special way to do that ? or maybe can you give me reference please ?

```
for(var i=0; i < element_array.length; i++){
    element_array[i].addEventListener("keyup", sum_values($sum_values));
}

function sum_values(values){

if(sid == '2'){
            <?php foreach ($values as $value) { ?>
                if(grade >= <?php echo $value->min; ?> && grade <= <?php echo $value->max; ?>)
                {
                    a.innerHTML = <?php echo $value->scale; ?>
                }
            <?php } ?>
```

And for your information.. this is what i get from my query that i want to pass then
[image]

Comment: you could use ajax instead of hardcoding it. but i have to ask, what is the problem? console errors?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Alex There's no console error but it keeps loading and never end... based on my case can i use this solution on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719864/how-to-pass-codeigniter-db-array-to-javascript-function)

Comment: the page keeps loading? e.g. nothing shows on screen? that's strange... are you sure you don't have any errors either in php or js? usually with just a js error your get a browser error and the page continues to render.

Comment: @Alex when i run Dev tool it show "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" it means there's something wrong with my code right :(

Comment: yea for sure. if you click the error it will tell you on what line and what character specifically is offending. it might be as simple as putting some quotes around things.

Comment: @Alex yeah it getting error in my hardcode <?php foreach ?> like code i shared before.. so how i fix my hardcode then bro ?

Comment: i don't know what the error is *specifically* so I can't help. maybe post a screen-grab of the error area from dev tools, so not just the error itself.

Comment: what your loop for? what is `element_array`?